# awk Count number of occurrences

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I made this awk command in a shell script to count total occurrences of the $4  and $5.

```
awk -F" " '{if($4=="A" && $5=="G") {print NR"\t"$0}}' file.txt > ag.txt && cat ag.txt | wc -l
awk -F" " '{if($4=="C" && $5=="T") {print NR"\t"$0}}' file.txt > ct.txt && cat ct.txt | wc -l

awk -F" " '{if($4=="T" && $5=="C") {print NR"\t"$0}}' file.txt > tc.txt && cat ta.txt | wc -l
awk -F" " '{if($4=="T" && $5=="A") {print NR"\t"$0}}' file.txt > ta.txt && cat ta.txt | wc -l
```

The output is #### (number) in shell. But I want to get rid of `> ag.txt && cat ag.txt | wc -l` and instead get output in shell like AG = ####.

This is input format:

```
>seq1 284 284 A G 27 100 16 11 16 11
>seq1 266 266 C T 27 100 16 11 16 11
>seq1 185 185 T - 24 100 10 14 10 14
>seq1 194 194 T C 24 100 12 12 12 12
>seq1 185 185 T AAA 24 100 10 14 10 14
>seq1 194 194 A G 24 100 12 12 12 12
>seq1 185 185 T A 24 100 10 14 10 14
```

I want output like this in the shell or in file for a single occurrences not other patterns.

```
AG 2
CT 1
TC 1
TA 1
```

Comment: Can you show us the formatted output you're aiming for, and perhaps include some sample input to test with?

Comment: The output you've added doesn't match the sample script you wrote. Do you really want something that will count pairs, or just count "A" and "G"?

Comment: I do it one by one. So basically I multiple the awk command in a shell script.

Comment: Okay, check my answer. Much more efficient. :-)

Comment: This question keeps changing.

Comment: Sorry! But this is final changes.

Comment: To be clear -- "chameleon questions" (which change their form after they're answered) are very much considered bad form. Please ensure that your questions are clear enough when first asked to contain everything needed to determine whether an answer is correct, and consider noting the discussion and consensus on the topic on meta: https://www.google.com/webhp?#q=site%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com%20chameleon%20questions

Comment: Are you REALLY trying to get output for specific combinations or is what you actually want to get output for all combinations that are exactly 2 letters (e.g. not "T -" and not "T AAA")?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, everything you're trying to do can likely be done within the awk script.  Here's how I'd count lines based on a condition:

```
awk -F" " '$4=="A" && $5=="G" {n++} END {printf("AG = %d\n", n)}' file.txt
```

- Awk scripts consist of `condition { statement }` pairs, so you can do away with the `if` entirely -- it's implicit.
- `n++` increments a counter whenever the condition is matched.
- The magic condition `END` is true after the last line of input has been processed.

Is this what you're after?  Why were you adding `NR` to your output if all you wanted was the line count?

Oh, and you might want to confirm whether you really need `-F" "`. By default, awk splits on whitespace. This option would only be required if your fields contain embedded tabs, I think.

---

**UPDATE #1** based on the edited question...

If what you're really after is a pair counter, an awk *array* may be the way to go.  Something like this:

```
awk '{a[$4 $5]++} END {for (pair in a) printf("%s %d\n", pair, a[pair])}' file.txt
```

Here's the breakdown.

- The first statement runs on every line, and increments a counter that is the index on an array (`a[]`) whose key is build from `$4` and `$5`.
- In the `END` block, we step through the array in a `for` loop, and for each index, print the index name and the value.

The output will not be in any particular order, as awk does not guarantee array order. If that's fine with you, then this should be sufficient. It should also be pretty efficient, because its max memory usage is based on the total number of combinations available, which is a limited set.

Example:

```
$ cat file
>seq1 284 284 A G 27 100 16 11 16 11
>seq1 266 266 C T 27 100 16 11 16 11
>seq1 227 227 T C 25 100 13 12 13 12
>seq1 194 194 A G 24 100 12 12 12 12
>seq1 185 185 T A 24 100 10 14 10 14
$ awk '/^>seq/ {a[$4 $5]++} END {for (p in a) printf("%s %d\n", p, a[p])}' file
CT 1
TA 1
TC 1
AG 2
```

---

**UPDATE #2** based on the revised input data and previously undocumented requirements.

With the extra data, you can still do this with a single run of awk, but of course the awk script is getting more complex with each new requirement. Let's try this as a longer one-liner:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{v["G"]; v["A"]; v["C"]; v["T"]} $4 in v && $5 in v {a[$4 $5]++} END {for (p in a) printf("%s %d\n", p, a[p])}' i
CT 1
TA 1
TC 1
AG 2
```

This works by first (in the magic `BEGIN` block) defining an array, `v[]`, to record "valid" records. The condition on the counter simply verifies that both `$4` and `$5` contain members of the array. All else works the same.

At this point, with the script running onto multiple lines anyway, I'd probably separate this into a small file. It could even be a stand-alone script.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
  v["G"]; v["A"]; v["C"]; v["T"]
}

$4 in v && $5 in v {
  a[$4 $5]++
}

END {
  for (p in a)
    printf("%s %d\n", p, a[p])
}
```

Much easier to read that way.

And if your goal is to count ONLY the combinations you mentioned in your question, you can handle the array slightly differently.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
  a["AG"]; a["TA"]; a["CT"]; a["TC"]
}

($4 $5) in a {
  a[$4 $5]++
}

END {
  for (p in a)
    printf("%s %d\n", p, a[p])
}
```

This only validates things that already have array indices, which are NULL per `BEGIN`.

The parentheses in the increment condition are not required, and are included only for clarity.

Comment: Thank you. I added my input file. Can you improve the code for all patterns?

Comment: Your first code works perfectly. How to do for different occurrences at once?

Comment: Your updated code print other patters as well which I do not want.

Comment: Ah, my telepathic powers must be lacking. You didn't include other patterns in your sample input. If you need conditions that restrict the processing, feel free to add those conditions yourself, or complete your question so that it matches your actual requirements. I'll update with the assumption that all data records start with `>seq`.

Comment: And I added my last update to this answer. Please consider ending the updates to your question, and if you have additional problems, starting a new question.

Comment: idk if it can happen in the real input but that would count any AT or GA or other undesirable combinations of the array indices. It also would produce no output for a desired combination that doesn't appear in the input while I'd expect a count of zero would be desirable.

Comment: @EdMorton True, but perhaps the description I've provided would be sufficient for the OP to build an array of valid combinations if there was risk that the data would include broken outliers like that. My knowledge of genetics is even smaller than my knowledge of awk, I didn't even know that what you mention might be a risk. :)

Comment: yeah, idk it's all just records and fields to me :-). My gut feeling is the OP really just wants all cases where $4 and $5 are each one letter but hasn't been able to express that yet.

Answer (score 0):

Just count them all then print the ones you care about:

```
$ awk '{cnt[$4$5]++} END{split("AG CT TC TA",t); for (i=1;i in t;i++) print t[i], cnt[t[i]]+0}' file
AG 2
CT 1
TC 1
TA 1
```

Note that this will produce a count of zero for any of your target pairs that don't appear in your input, e.g. if you want a count of "XY"s too:

```
$ awk '{cnt[$4$5]++} END{split("AG CT TC TA XY",t); for (i=1;i in t;i++) print t[i], cnt[t[i]]+0}' file
AG 2
CT 1
TC 1
TA 1
XY 0
```

If that's desirable, check if other solutions do the same.

Actually, this might be what you REALLY want, just to make sure $4 and $5 are single upper case letters:

```
$ awk '$4$5 ~ /^[[:upper:]]{2}$/{cnt[$4$5]++} END{for (i in cnt) print i, cnt[i]}' file
TA 1
AG 2
TC 1
CT 1
```